# Get the last element that fulfills condition in eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, subquery

I have 2 models, Queue and Action.

A queue has many actions, those actions could be pending, redirected, finished, etc.

I add an action for every action the given queue had been taken.

So, the first action is 'Pending' as soon as I add a queue object.

I need to retrieve the queues which their last action is either Pending (status_id = 1) or Redirected (status_id = 5)

My tables look like this

qms_queue
id

qms_actions
id status_id queue_id

My approach was something like this:

```
$queue_query->whereHas('actions', function ($query) {
            $query->where('id', function ($query2) {
                $query2->from('qms_actions')
                    ->select('id')
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                    ->limit(1);
            });
        })->whereIn('status_id', [1,5]);
```

But with that I retrieve the action that has status_id being either 1 or 5, but not being the last one of the given queue, so, every queue is returned.

I am not able to figure out how to do this in eloquent. Could anybody please help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this, if it's ok to load the queues that has not the wanted actions :

```
$queue_query->with('actions', function ($query) {
            $query->whereIn('status_id', [1,5]);
            $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
            $query->limit(1);
        });
```

---

Try this :

```
$queues = $queue_query->whereHas('actions', function ($query) {
            $query->where('id', function ($query2) {
                $query2->from('qms_actions')
                    ->select('id')
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                    ->whereIn('status_id', [1,5]);
                    ->limit(1);
            });
        })->get();
```

And you can get the action like that :

```
foreach ($queues as $queue) {
    //$queue->actions->first();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, not exactly, I have to fetch a list of the next of the queues that last action is strictly one of 1 or 5.

Comment: Cool, that's almost the solution I guess, however testing the 2nd subquery it just returns the absolute last action, not the last action for each queue :S

Comment: Mmmmm thanks for your support, I can't find a way to make it work as intended, I would need to filter through the actions that I can have from this query:

select * from (select * from qms_actions where queue_id = QUEUE_ID order by updated_at desc limit 1) as qms_actions1 where status_id in (1,5)

Trying to do the less calls posible, if posible